# Excel Build a formula to look for the record and match the value, if found return a value YES

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Find and match the project code in another file, if a record is found, then check if the IP address value contains in that record, if yes return value YES.

[image: Excel screenshot]

Comment: Is it separate workbook or sheet? Did you try anything?

Comment: @TarangP How do you expect the OP to ask his question succinctly without using an image of the spreadsheet?

Comment: In the image I did mention file1 & file2, they are from two different files. But it does not matter whether different file or in same file with different tab as we can always select the range or the source across. 

I only know the basic of vlookup. And I know vlooup alone can't handle this, that's why I post it here for answer. 

I'm new to this portal, what is OP?

Comment: So my post is answered. Do I need to close it? how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data from File2 is in the same workbook and on a worksheet called "File2", here is one of the solutions using VLOOKUP:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(E$2,VLOOKUP($B3,File2!$A$2:$E$6,5,0))),"YES")
```

If your version of excel can use XLOOKUP, here is the solution using XLOOKUP:

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(F$2,XLOOKUP($B3,File2!$A$2:$A$6,File2!$E$2:$E$6))),"YES")
```

Here is a screenshot of my workings:
[image]

Let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Great. This solved my problem. I used the xlookup. Many thanks.